# Postgres and temporary tables

Tags: postgresql, session, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure that use temp table and explicitly drops it when done.

What happed when same procedure is run at same time by 2 different sessions? Sessions are run as single user (webapp).

Will one session interfere with temp table, and data inside it, of other session?

I'm using Postgres 9.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postgresql [temporary tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createtable.html) are unique for each session, so no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not totally wrong, the result would be one temp table per query in your procedure which generates the temp table, so the two temp tables would not disturb eachother.